# please help me on how to make my ubuntu server 16.04 accessible through the internet. i can access it on LAN. i ve even done port forwarding

Tags: apache2

hello guys just set up my server (ubuntu 16.04lts )and i can access it on the LAN but am trying to access it over the internet but i cant get through. i set up  port forwarding but still no luck on it thanks.

Comment: What about it do you want accessible?  Your question doesn't make it clear what you're asking, and this has most likely been answered before.

Comment: First we need to know what you want to acces of the internet then we can help you out

Comment: @cyber_star. i want to host a web app using my own server. i can access it on my LAN but have failed to access the server through the internet. even after setting port forwarding. thanks in advance

Comment: @AbdallaNiYang i had the same problem what the problem was that my router din't support loopback so i could NOT acces my own external address but my friend could. Check if the port you use is open with this site: http://www.canyouseeme.org/  The other thing is that some ISP's block the http ports of being opened.

Comment: @AbdallaNiYang Please check these posts: [this](http://askubuntu.com/a/876062/566421) and [point 6 of this](http://askubuntu.com/a/811416/566421).