# Ubuntu Server -- Outside SSH Access

Tags: networking, ssh, mac, apple

I have setup an old MacBook now running Ubuntu. I have set up OpenSSH and have everything ready to have it act as a server for home media, fun scripts/crons, learning more programming, etc. My keys are on the host Ubuntu system for my other three machines. It works great on my local network but obviously, it doesn't work when I am not on my own home WiFi.

It would be awesome if I could SSH in from any WiFi on any of my machines (which keys are added). I am not sure how I go about setting this up -- I have been reading some of the port forwarding, static IP, DNS, etc. but I am struggling to figure out how this works exactly or how to get it set up. What I've concluded is my next step is port forwarding.

I am playing with the Subnets/NAT of my AT&T router a bit but am having no luck. I would love to have a real word to ssh username@domain.com but what's important to me right now is just being able to SSH in out of home network even if it's typing the IP...

Can anyone point me in the right direction or offer some guidance? I feel like I understand the issue but the AT&T UI is a bit confusing. I apologize for my ignorance, and would sincerely appreciate if anyone could break it down a bit more for me.

Comment: Time ago, I wrote an [**answer**](http://askubuntu.com/q/876046/566421), which can throw some light here :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On your router you need to set port forwarding. Let's say you Ubuntu machine has IP 192.168.1.10. In your router you set port 22 to be forwarded to address 192.168.1.10 and you are set, you can access your SSH from outside using your outside address. To find out what is your outside address, go to http://whatismyipaddress.com
This will work till your outside address changes. Then you will need to find out again what is your address, or have static address or use dynamic DNS. But first set the basic thing in step 1, access via IP.
Hope this helps

Comment: Understood, that makes sense. For some reason I am having a really hard time figuring out the router interface. I think once I get over hurdle I will be golden.

Comment: Then please mark the question as answered. Glad to help