# SCP from server to local

Tags: server, ssh

I am new to Ubuntu but I have to do a small script which backups all my files on my server to my local computer. I made a script on my server called backupscript and put the following command

```
zip -r Backupfile /home/ubuntu
sudo scp -P 22 /home/ubuntu/Backupfile.zip user@ipaddress:/home/user
```

I save it and execute this script from terminal `./backupscript`

But then I get a message ssh: connection to host ipaddress port 22: connection lost.

I opened port 22 in my host computer using this
`sudo ufw allow 22`

but still unable to scp the file from my server to host computer.

Comment: can you modify your script to include `-v` immediately after `scp`, rerun the command and edit your question ti include the results. This should give some diagnostic information that may help solve the issue

Comment: Also, I am not sure why you have `sudo` at the start of the scp line. Whilst I dont think that its a problem, it would help diagnostics if you could rerun with out the `sudo` command

Comment: firstly, just try to ssh into your box

Comment: If in front of your local network has a router you must forward the router's port 22 to your local computer. Check [**this answer**](https://askubuntu.com/a/876062/566421) for more details.

Comment: Maybe the better and easiest way is to copy files from the local machine itself. Something as: `sudo scp -P 22 user@remote-server:/home/ubuntu/Backupfile.zip /home/user`. So you can create cronjob on the *remote server* that will create the backup, and cronjob on the *local machine* that will download the backup.

Comment: btw -- rsync is often a better option than scp. If you're doing a backup, scp will copy everything, every time. rsync will just send the changes and therefore saves time (esp if youre on a slow connection)