# How to connect to a certain port on SSH

Tags: server, ssh, ip, port-forwarding, client

So, I am setting up an ssh server. I have installed the ssh-server program on my server. However, I didn't want to connect to it through port 22, because reasons, so I set the server to listen through another port (2584). How do i set up my client to also connect through port 2584 rather than port 22?

Comment: You can setup `~/.ssh/config` file to simplify your ssh terminal commands, here is a complete manual: [How To Configure Custom Connection Options for your SSH Client](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-configure-custom-connection-options-for-your-ssh-client). Also in [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/986245/566421) of mine is presented an example.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Assuming you are using normal `ssh` command it is the additional parameter `-p` (see the man page of [`man ssh`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/ssh)). E.g:

```
$ ssh -p 2584 user@host
```

Comment: Thanks so much! This worked! Now I dont have to use teamviewer...

Comment: I can't, I am a new user, and my upvotes are not displayed.

Answer (score 3):

Note that `ssh` accepts commands in the URI form, such as `ssh://user@host.com:<port>`. It is perfectly valid to do the following:

```
ssh  ssh://myuser@domain_name.com:2222
```

Alternatively, to avoid specifying port each time, you can declare it within `~/.ssh/config`. See [steeldriver's answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1111996/295286) for details.