# Login with SSH authorized key with changed SSH port

Tags: ssh, login

I changed my SSH port in the `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` file and then restarted the ssh service. I implemented fail2ban and updated the port to my SSH under that config. I also then implemented the UFW firewall and allowed incoming connections to my new SSH port.

However, when I try and login with my SSH key using `ssh -i /Users/myuser/.ssh/vpsssh user@555.555.555.555` it's trying to connect to port 22 instead of the defined port I have.

Comment: Server and client do not about each other automatically. They both use the default port 22, unles is changed, on `sshd_config` for server, or specified on command for cliente like [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/660556/260379)

Comment: They could be trying to login to an Ubuntu server from a Windows PC, which I think is still on topic.

Comment: Is there a reason you're using a different key for each host you connect to?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You can specify a non-default port on the `ssh` client command line using the `-p` option. From `man ssh`:

```
 -p port
         Port to connect to on the remote host.  This can be specified on
         a per-host basis in the configuration file.
```

You may wish to put both the port number and the identity file location for the host in a `~/.ssh/config` file so that they don't need to be specified every time on the command line.

Ex.

```
Host myremotehost
  Hostname      555.555.555.555
  User          user
  Port          20002
  IdentityFile  /Users/myuser/.ssh/vpsssh
```

Then you will be able to use:

```
ssh myremotehost
```

Comment: Probably useful to many when you start defining that kind of configuration: [How do I configure SSH so it dosen't try all the identity files automatically?](https://superuser.com/questions/268776/how-do-i-configure-ssh-so-it-dosent-try-all-the-identity-files-automatically).

Answer (score 5):

Note that `ssh` accepts commands in the URI form, such as `ssh://user@host.com:<port>`. Based on that, what I do when logging in to a remote server with a private key is the following:

```
ssh -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa ssh://myuser@domain_name.com:2222
```

Comment: This answer over at "Unix Linux S.O." https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/75668/why-doesnt-the-ssh-command-follow-rfc-on-uri explains that URI is actually not accepted by SSH. I have tried this in my updated Ubuntu 20.04 and it didn't work so I don't think this answer is valid.