# rsync to remote directory

Tags: ssh, rsync

I  tried to update the home directory to a backup computer as

```
rsync -avru --exclude-from='/home/me/exclude-me.txt' /home/me/* assistant@assistant.local:/home/assistant/* -p 2222
```

but get an error

```
Unexpected remote arg: assistant@assistant.local:
rsync error: syntax or usage error (code 1) at main.c(1361) [sender=3.1.2]
```

What's the problem with my codes?

Comment: I guess it is the `-p 2222` which I think is intended to use port 2222 for SSH. in `rsync` the option `-p` is different and SSH arguments should bepassed as `-e 'ssh -p 2234'` for `rsync`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For `rsync` the `-p` option means to *preserve permissions* and does not take an argument. Therefore your command cannot be parsed correctly and you get an error.

If you want to change the SSH port on which `rsync` should connect, use the command as follows.

```
rsync -avru --exclude-from='/home/me/exclude-me.txt' -e 'ssh -p 2222' \ 
/home/me/ \
assistant@assistant.local:/home/assistant/
```

Comment: To simplify my further work, I would create `~/.ssh/config` file as it is shown here: https://askubuntu.com/a/1111996/566421.

Answer (score 1):

The target shouldn't have any wildcards. Best to learn to use the trailing /, or not, as needed.

```
-p in rsync is permissions, not port. From the manpage:
        -p, --perms                 preserve permissions
```

rsync has used ssh for remote connections by default for at least a decade. No need to specify -e anything. The port can be added to the URL - userid@remote-server:port/path/to/target/ . If the userid is the same as the source machine, it isn't needed.

Since ssh is used by default, using the ~/.ssh/config file to handle non-standard settings like alternate ports, different userids, or different keys makes rsync commands simpler. It is handy for using a name when either the DNS name is ugly or only IPs are possible too.  I find the config file is a good way to document, in a useful, all the foreign systems where I have accounts, logins, and use non-standard ports.

```
  There are two different ways for rsync  to  contact  a  remote  system:
       using  a  remote-shell program as the transport (such as ssh or rsh) or
       contacting an rsync daemon directly via TCP.  The  remote-shell  transâ
       port  is used whenever the source or destination path contains a single
       colon (:) separator after a host specification.
```

But this is more about ssh-fu, than rsync-fu.

The rsync manpage is extremely comprehensive.  Many people find that explainshell.com is helpful for complex commands like rsync or find. If you plug the original command into explainshell, the -p jumps out as an issue.

So, after the above simplifications (especially using the ~/.ssh/config file, the commands becomes:

```
$ rsync -avru --exclude-from='/home/me/exclude-me.txt' ~/* assistant@assistant.local:2222/home/assistant/
```

I would put the userid, unfriendly hostname, port into the config and do it this way:

```
$ rsync -avz --exclude-from='/home/me/exclude-me.txt' ~/ backsrv:
```

The ~/* or /home/me/* will miss anything that begins with a period, like config files and the ~/.config/ directory. If you want those, and you should, then a specific regex is needed OR just use /home/me as the source without any regex pattern. See above.
Note how I didn't specify any directory on the target?  By default, the userid's HOME is used.
And don't forget about the --dry-run option:

```
        -n, --dry-run               perform a trial run with no
changes made
```

If the goal is for a daily backup, perhaps using a tool with versioned backups would make sense?